Dystopian British film from the early 1970s featuring a stadium concert
I am wracking my brain trying to recall the name a dystopian British film from the early 1970s I believe, presented in documentary style with a narrator setting the stage and describing the culture.
It's set in the near future (for the time), where Britain is a totalitarian, xenophobic culture. I thought it featured Roger Daltrey, but IMDB doesn't support this. During the concert, the crowd sings Albion, and the act has the Daltrey-clone emerging from a prison set and singing.
No searches for dystopian British Cinema have produced any suspects.

I'm not familiar with "Albion"...it doesn't sound like a well known 70's song...who did it originally? Do you have a reference for this song?

I think OP just means old English songs.

Sounds like the British musical film Privilege from 1967.

The story is presented as a narrated documentary, set in a near-future 1970s [kind of totalitarian] England, and concerning a disillusioned pop singer, Steven Shorter (Paul Jones), who is the most-loved celebrity in the country. His stage show involves him appearing on stage in a jail cell with handcuffs, beaten by police, to the horror and sympathy of the audience. It is described that the two main parties of England have formed a coalition government and encourage the success of Shorter to placate the masses and divert them from political activity. 

Jones's face is a bit Daltreyish, I guess, and they sing Onward Christian Soldiers at some point. You can see the scene where he sings in 'prison' on stage in the trailer:



